# Indexing and iterating through a dictionary of lists in Tcl

Tags: loops, tcl

I have the following situation in TCL:

```
dictionary_name {
  name_list {apple banana carrot peach} 
  type_list {fruit fruit vegetable fruit} 
  amount_list {1 3 4 2} 
}
```

I want to process them one by one in a loop for example
loop 1 would be:

```
name apple 
type fruit 
amount 1
```

and loop 2:

```
name banana 
type fruit 
amount 3
```

etc. How can I do this?

I have created 'foreach {list_name list_value} $dictionary_name' loop to separate the names and values but I am unsure how to continue from here

Answer (score 4):

The [`foreach` command](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/foreach.htm) lets you iterate over multiple lists at once:

```
foreach name [dict get $dictionary_name name_list]   \
        type [dict get $dictionary_name type_list]   \
        amt  [dict get $dictionary_name amount_list] \
{
    puts "name $name"
    puts "type $type"
    puts "amount $amt"
}
```

outputs

```
name apple
type fruit
amount 1
name banana
type fruit
amount 3
name carrot
type vegetable
amount 4
name peach
type fruit
amount 2
```

The [`dict with` command](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm#M27) gives you access to the keys of your dictionary as plain variables. This removes the 3 `dict get` commands and gives the same output as above:

```
dict with dictionary_name {
    foreach name $name_list type $type_list amt $amount_list {
        puts "name $name"
        puts "type $type"
        puts "amount $amt"
    }
}
```

Note `dict with dictionary_name` -- no `$`. That command wants the dictionary ***variable*** not the dictionary ***value***

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach n {0 1 2 3} {
    puts ""
    foreach x {name type amount} {
        set key ${x}_list
        set value_for_n [lindex [dict get $dictionary_name $key] $n]
        puts "$x $value_for_n"
    }
}
```